# Destroy or remove a view in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm currently trying to implement a destroy/remove method for views but I can't get a generic solution to work for all my views.

I was hoping there would be an event to attach to the controller, so that when a new request comes through it destroys previous views **then** loads the new ones.

Is there any way to do this without having to build a remove function for each view?

Comment: Could you give an example of what your view eco-system is?  Your question makes me think there are many views on the page at once.  I can't quite visualize what you are trying to do and thus can't offer an answer that might be what you need.

Comment: some other patterns from these great posts: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/ http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/backbone-js-lessons-learned-and-improved-sample-app/#comment-57351

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Without knowing all the information... You could bind a reset trigger to your model or controller:

```
this.bind("reset", this.updateView);
```

and when you want to reset the views, trigger a reset.

For your callback, do something like:

```
updateView: function() {
  view.remove();
  view.render();
};
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. The View's remove function just remove's that view's element from the DOM ([see here](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-remove)). I think this guy wants to remove the view object entirely.

Comment: this.remove() ends up calling jquery's remove(), which also removes data and events... Nevertheless I think you also have to call this.undelegateEvents to unbind from other events, like custom events or changes to the model..

Comment: `this.remove()` calls `this.stopListening()` and `this.$el.remove()`. The first removes all event listeners added using `this.listenTo(...)`. The second removes all event listeners add using jQuery.  Between the two, you should be covered unless you used some other means of adding event listeners.  So this answer is correct and gets +1 from me.

Answer (score 163):

I had to be absolutely sure the view was not just removed from DOM but also completely unbound from events.

```
destroy_view: function() {

    // COMPLETELY UNBIND THE VIEW
    this.undelegateEvents();

    this.$el.removeData().unbind(); 

    // Remove view from DOM
    this.remove();  
    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);

}
```

Seemed like overkill to me, but other approaches did not completely do the trick.

Comment: for what I've seen, this.remove() should call jQuery's remove, which should remove the element from the DOM but also remove data and events attached to it. So I guess the call to undelegateEvents and removeData  shouldn't be necessary... Am I right?

Comment: @opensas Events were persisting past the this.remove() despite the element being removed from the DOM. this.undelegateEvents() was needed for all the events to unbind. As I said, it felt like overkill, but it did the trick.

Comment: I like it. Eventhough you should be using `this.$el` instead of `$(this.el)` ;)

Comment: +1 for a good answer to my problem, +1 for writing your first answer :)

Comment: This answer is a life saver. Backbone should provide an easier way to remove views. This is the main cause of bugs on my backbone based code.

Comment: Another +1 for your first answer, esp since it's a great one.  Answer more!

Comment: Where should I call the `destroy` function in my view?

Comment: My view is not getting re-rendered on destroying and creating it again. Is it because of `this.remove()`?

Comment: @user2235057 that would be the equivalent of attempting to raise someone from the dead. Create a new view the same way you created the one you destroyed, don't attempt to reuse that instance.

Comment: I am creating new view `new TripsView()` but it is not getting rendered.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Works, but I do not understand what `.removeData()` does, and was unable to locate the method in the backbone docs.

Comment: This is cargo cult programming; if just calling this.remove() doesn't do the trick there is something else wrong in your code.

Comment: nice answer, but what about Child Views, can someone put some generic bombproof code for that as well?

Answer (score 20):

I know I am late to the party, but hopefully this will be useful for someone else. If you are using backbone v0.9.9+, you could use, `listenTo` and `stopListening`

```
initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
}
```

`stopListening` is called automatically by `remove`. You can read more [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) and [here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove)

Answer (score 8):

This is what I've been using. Haven't seen any issues.

```
destroy: function(){
  this.remove();
  this.unbind();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to current Backbone documentation....

view.remove()

Removes a view and its el from the DOM, and calls stopListening to remove any bound events that the view has listenTo'd.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
destroyView : function () {
    this.$el.remove();
}
```

Comment: Have to kill listeners also with `this.stopListening()` and then `return this` for good measure

Answer (score 0):

You could use the way to solve the problem!

```
initialize:function(){
    this.trigger('remove-compnents-cart');
    var _this = this;
    Backbone.View.prototype.on('remove-compnents-cart',function(){
        //Backbone.View.prototype.remove;
        Backbone.View.prototype.off();
        _this.undelegateEvents();
    })
}
```

Another way：Create a global variable,like this:`_global.routerList`

```
initialize:function(){
    this.routerName = 'home';
    _global.routerList.push(this);
}
/*remove it in memory*/
for (var i=0;i<_global.routerList.length;i++){
    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(_global.routerList[i]);
}
```

Comment: The first approach worked for me, I ran into a similar problem with views ghosting and the events were firing multiple times when each view was being recreated when you submitted the form