# How do I destroy this Backbone.js View instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, backbone.js

```
var CheckboxView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName:'div',
        template: _.template(item_temp,{}),
        events:{
            'click .checkoff_friend':'toggleCheckFriend',
        },
        initialize: function(){
        },
        render:function(){

        },
        toggleCheckFriend:function(){
            //destroy this View instance. 
        }
    });

var cv = new CheckboxView();
```

How do I destroy the instance? When toggle is activated, I want the instance of that view to dissapear forever.

Answer (score 6):

My answer for a similar question was received well, and has worked well for me.  Here's a look at my destroy_view function

(orig. question https://stackoverflow.com/a/11534056/986832)
Response:

I had to be absolutely sure the view was not just removed from DOM but also completely unbound from events.

```
destroy_view: function() {

    //COMPLETELY UNBIND THE VIEW
    this.undelegateEvents();

    $(this.el).removeData().unbind(); 

    //Remove view from DOM
    this.remove();  
    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);

    }
```

Seemed like overkill to me, but other approaches did not completely do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Do not assign the instance to any variable (I don't see any need to since Views in backbone are driven by events), and in your `toggleCheckFriend` method remove all data and events, which makes the instance available for garbage collection.

```
    toggleCheckFriend:function(){
    $(this.el).removeData().unbind();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does that View have a model behind it?

If you want the model removed (from the db), you can use: `this.model.destroy()`

After that, you can remove just the View itself from the DOM by calling `this.remove()`.  Documentation mentions that it is the equivalent of `$(this.el).remove()`.

Note that the 'this' above refers to the View itself, so you would have to `_.bindAll(this, 'toggleCheckFriend')`

Comment: You don't need _.bindAll(this, 'toggleCheckFriend'). The context for DOM event callbacks will automatically be the view.

Comment: @JohnnyO: I mainly have that in there for piping commands.  Just in case there are elements that can trigger it besides the user directly triggering it. (i.e. the page has a CheckAllCheckBox)