# Backbone single page application - Memory leak

Tags: backbone.js

I have got 6-7 pages application which is using backbone views, jQuery and high charts. I have noticed that it is leaking memory. It become unresponsive if I leave it running for 10 minutes. Someone suggested me to destroy views when not in use and I did this according to this answer.

[Destroy or remove a view in Backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569704/destroy-or-remove-a-view-in-backbone-js)

Which improved app but still I have got memory issues. I'll appreciate if someone could guide me in correct direction. Is there anything else I can do to improve memory leaks?

Answer (score 2):

Most of memory leaks happen because of ghost events.

I suggest using `listenTo` when binding to events inside views. Calling `view.remove()` will automatically unbind them.

Comment: +1, also you should avoid adding element to the DOM in the loop. Do it once. Also if you use a `comparator` avoid adding `models` to the `collection` in the loop too.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to detect the root cause and only then fix it.

[Tools for debugging memory leaks in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573252/tools-for-debugging-memory-leaks-in-javascript)

Also I suggest to watch this screencast http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3ugr9BJqIs