# Backbone remove view

Tags: backbone.js, view

Is this normal in Backbone that after a .remove() on a view I'm still able to access the events object via console.log ?

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize : function () {
        console.log("hey");
    },

    events: {
        "click ul#products li a": "item"
    }           

});

var vi = new View;
vi.off();
vi.remove();
vi.undelegateEvents();

console.log(vi);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Destroy or remove a view in Backbone.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569704/destroy-or-remove-a-view-in-backbone-js)

Comment: Your `vi` is not an event object but view object so as long as that variable still in scope your view won't get garbage collected.

Comment: May I ask you a exemple j03w ? http://jsfiddle.net/RDch8/200/

Comment: You can set your object to undefined `vi = undefined` after destroying the view.