# Deleting a variable in Backbone

Tags: javascript, variables, backbone.js, delete-operator

Iam developing a cross platform application and iam using backbone framework.

i have many views in them and i render the views as follows

For eg:

```
sampleFunction: function() {
    var sampleObject = new window.sampleView();

    sampleObject.Render();
}
```

Then one of my friend happen to see my code and he said, every variable created inside a function should be deleted,

```
sampleFunction: function() {
    var sampleObject = new window.sampleView();

    sampleObject.Render();
    delete sampleObject;
}
```

I searched the whole web and couldn't find anything relevant to his theory. In web it says a variable is never deleted.

so i showed him a sample like below,

```
<script>
    function onBodyLoad() {
        var test = "i'am alive";

        delete test;
        alert(test);
    }
</script>

<body onLoad="onBodyLoad()">
```

- So my question is what delete operator really do? just used for deleting an object property?
- What happens to the object and variables that brought up to the DOM when using an MV framework like   backbone?
- Does the object and variables will be cleared when a new view is loaded?
- Do we need to unbind or destory view each time just before loading another view?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the delete operator, it will delete the property from the object. It wont do anything related to Freeing memory.

In backbone, whenever model is attached with some views it'll be in DOM. view.remove(), will remove the view and the attached model from DOM.

Creating a new view wont delete existing views. You can set a listener to remove the existing views when you create new views.

See this question: [Destroy or remove a view in Backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569704/destroy-or-remove-a-view-in-backbone-js)